# Distinct Count with two tables

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have two tables on Access, Customer and Transaction. I'm trying to find the total # of transactions sorted by Dogs (0-3). The Transaction table has a line for each item bought, so multiple lines can be for one TransactionID.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT Customer.Dogs, COUNT(Transaction.TransactionID) AS TotTrans
FROM Transaction, Customer
WHERE Transaction.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
GROUP BY Dogs
```

And I get

```
Dogs | TotTrans
0    | 130104
1    | 59132
2    | 17811
3    | 1401
```

Obviously this counts the total rows in the Transaction Table and sorts them by # of dogs. However, it is counting for the duplicates in the Transaction Table (e.g. There are three rows with TransactionID = 2, because in that transaction the customer bought 3 items. The Count is obviously including the extra 2 rows).

When I try to do `COUNT(DISTINCT Transaction.TransactionID)` it doesn't work, and the message

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(DISTINCT Transaction.TransactionID)'.

I have looked around, but can't seem to find the solution. I think part of the problem stems from the fact that I'm selecting two attributes.

If anyone could help explain what to do and the logic behind it, that would be great!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Access, sorry, will edit.

Comment: Note, by the way, that implicit joins (having two tables in the from clause) is a deprecated syntax, and it's recommended to switch to the modern, explicit, syntax: Learn how to use explicit join syntax. Aaron Bertrand did some [**writting**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it

Comment: I will look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should join the customer table with an already distinct-ed table (using inner query)

```
SELECT Customer.Dogs, COUNT(distinctTransactions.TransactionID) AS TotTrans
FROM (select distinct TransactionID,CustomerID from Transaction) as 
distinctTransactions, Customer
WHERE distinctTransactions.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
GROUP BY Dogs
```

Answer (score 1):

You should learn to use proper `join` syntax.  Also, table aliases make the query easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT c.Dogs, COUNT(DISTINCT t.TransactionID) AS TotTrans
FROM Transaction t JOIN
     Customer c
     ON t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.Dogs
ORDER BY c.Dogs;
```

Comment: I'm just starting so I will look into "join" more this weekend, thank you for directing me towards that!